# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: php, soap

It tells me that `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`, when trying to call this SOAP API.

[image]

I am doing this way

```
$client = new    SoapClient("http://gateway.XXXXXXX/gateway/api/creditcards/creditcardAPI.asmx?wsdl");

$params = array("clsCreditCardAPIBE" => (Object) array(
   "Username" => 'blabla',
   "Password" => "Barrel of Oil",
   "ProviderPIN" => 500,
   "AccountID" => 1234
    .......
));


$response = $client->__soapCall("Initiate_Deposit", $params);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate the client first, and then start using it

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://yourdomain.com?wsdl");
```

Comment: I am already doing that. I know how to do that, i am asking what is wrong in my call. :-)

Comment: It looks like the method __soapCall is not known to be a part of client and your wsdl contains no info on it - before calling a method you need to verify it exists and is described.